# Нахождение всех пикселей изображения

Tags: c#, цвета, winforms, изображения

Пишу курсовую, необходимо найти каждый пиксель в изображении,знаю что через `bitmap` и `GetPixel()`, не самый лучший вариант, но преподу больше и не требуется. Мне удалось составить алгоритм нахождения пикселя по конкретным координатам,код ниже

```
Bitmap layer = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image, new Size(pictureBox1.Width,pictureBox1.Height));
    progressBar1.Maximum = layer.Height - 1;
    for (int y = 0; y < layer.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < layer.Width; x++)
        {
             Color Pixel = layer.GetPixel(x, y);
             layer.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(layer.GetPixel(1,1).ToArgb()));
             pictureBox2.Image = layer;       
        }
        progressBar1.Value = y;
     }
```

Но при подстановке переменных X и Y происходит перенос изображения на другой `picturebox`, я уже как только не извращался))). Подскажите каким способом можно осуществить обход изображения?(Язык программирования C# Windows Form)

Comment: @factura, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: какой пиксел ищется? Переменная Color Pixel нигде не используется?

Answer (score 1):

На сколько я понимаю, целью был следующий код:

```
Bitmap layerOrig = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
Bitmap layer2 = new Bitmap(layerOrig.Width,layerOrig.Height)

progressBar1.Maximum = layer.Height - 1;

for (int y = 0; y < layer.Height; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < layer.Width; x++)
    {
         Color pixel = layer.GetPixel(x, y);
         layer2.SetPixel(x, y, pixel);

         pictureBox2.Image = layer2;       
    }
    progressBar1.Value = y;
 }
```